# "secret not found" reported by ExternalSecret

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets, argocd, vault, external-secrets-operator

I have been struggling with this issue for the past 2 days and I'm stuck. I'm using External Secrets Operator to obtain secrets from Vault: https://external-secrets.io/

It seems ExternalSecret is not creating the secret. This is my yaml file:

```
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: ape-external-secrets
  namespace: ape-test
spec:
  data:
  - remoteRef:
    secretKey: secret-ape-username
      key: secret-ape
      property: secret-ape-username
  - remoteRef:
    secretKey: secret-ape-password
      key: secret-ape
      property: secret-ape-password
  refreshInterval: 1h
  secretStoreRef:
    kind: SecretStore
    name: ape-vault-eso
  target:
    creationPolicy: Owner
    name: secret-ape
```

The error given by ExternalSecret K8s object is: **secret not found**

I looked and indeed there is no *secret-ape* secret created.

For Secret Store, I'm using the [K8s authentication method](https://external-secrets.io/v0.6.0-rc1/provider/hashicorp-vault/#kubernetes-authentication) to obtain credentials from Vault:

```
apiVersion: external-secrets.io/v1beta1
kind: SecretStore
metadata:
  name: ape-vault-eso
  namespace: ape-test
spec:
  provider:
    vault:
      auth:
        kubernetes:
          mountPath: k8s-dv1
          role: ape-app-kv-ro
          serviceAccountRef:
            name: ape-svc-dv
      path: kv/secret-ape
      server: 'https://dv-vault.xyz.local'
      version: v2
```

No error is given by the SecretStore so it looks like it is validated properly. Message is **store validated**

I'm deploying both of these via ArgoCD. Any insights into what I may be doing wrong? From the documentation here, it says ExternalSecrets object should create the secret.

Comment: Just to make sure - are you positive the referred secrets exist in Vault?

Comment: Does the Secret Store say "valid" within `.status.conditions` and does the external secrets operator have any errors?

Comment: the names of the secret and the version were correct, but my path was not. Thank you for chiming in!

Comment: @KevinB I am also facing the same issue. It says it cannot find the secret. What should be the path which should be used?